# Caller function with optional argument of varying type

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, void

I am trying to write a caller function that can take an optional argument of varying template type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f_int(int x){std::cout << "f_int\n";}
void f_double(double x){std::cout << "f_double\n";}
void f_void(void){std::cout << "f_void\n";}

template<typename T>
void caller(void (*fun)(T), T arg)
{
    (*fun)(arg); 
}


int main()
{
  caller(f_int, 3);
  caller(f_double, 2.1);
  caller(f_void);         // compilation error
  caller(f_void, void);   // compilation error
  void* p;
  caller(f_void, *p);     // compilation error
}
```

When writing this code, I was hoping that `T` could be of type `void`. Can it be? If yes, why does the above code not work? Is `void` a valid type or is only `void*` a valid type?

Comment: `f_void` has zero function parameters and `*fun` given `void (*fun)(T)` has one function parameter, so those can never match. That `(void)` as a function parameter list means the same as `()` is just a special case to support C habits and does not work with a template dependent type which is later determined to be `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do most of it with a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and [perfect forwarding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward):

```
template<typename F, class... Args>
void caller(F func, Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

//...

caller(f_int, 3);
caller(f_double, 2.1);
caller(f_void);
```

You may also return the value from the called function in the function template by using `auto`, even when called function is declared `void`:

```
int f_int(int x) {
    return x*2;
}
double f_double(double x) {
    return x*1.5;
}
void f_void(void) {
    std::cout << "f_void\n";
}

template<typename F, class... Args>
auto caller(F func, Args&&... args) {          // note the "auto"
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);  // and return
}

//...

auto rv1 = caller(f_int, 3);
auto rv2 = caller(f_double, 2.1);
caller(f_void);                                // you can't assign void though
```